# I have two problems. My ubuntu don't load without nomodeset and my graphics aren't working

Tags: graphics, display-resolution, nomodeset

During installation when in tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 my screen was stuck on the Ubuntu loading. I found a solution of nomodeset in GRUB screen but when i added it my screen resolution is stuck on 800x600 and my graphic card aren't working. I tried to remove nomodeset but after removing blank screen appears till i shut down my laptop manually.[image]
On running lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' command I get the output as shown in the image[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: done buddy. please check

Comment: Please don't post terminal screenshots. You can copy text from terminal. I am writing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install proprietary drivers. Run in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-drivers-430
```

Then remove `nomodeset` and disable Secure Boot in BIOS if applicable.

Reboot and all should work.